# heroku js.erb file outputs forms it's supposed to render as text

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

this is the site:  https://deadindustry-newnew-recruit.herokuapp.com/

here is the github:  daveasdf/deadindustry_newnew_recruit

when you enter the form, it's supposed to render the form, and the list of supporters on the right, but instead it spits out the text version of them at https://deadindustry-newnew-recruit.herokuapp.com/supporters.js, which is some random webpage.

i'm no developer, i'm just a musician, so i appreciate any and all help.   also, please check out my band:  soundcloud.com/whorwood

here's the specifics:

page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    TEXT
  </div>
</div>
<br>


<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="home_form">
      <%= render "supporters/form" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="home_list">
    <br>
    <%= render 'supporters/show_supporters' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
class SupportersController < ApplicationController

  ...  
  def create
    @supporter = Supporter.new(supporter_params)
    @supporters = Supporter.all.order(created_at: :desc)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  ...
```

create.js

```
<% if @supporter.save %>
    $("#home_list").html("<%= j render 'show_supporters' %>")
    $("home_form").html("<%= j render 'form' %>")
<% else %>
    $("#home_form").html("<%= j render 'form', supporter: @supporter %>") 
    $('#build_error').remove();
    <% if @supporter.errors.any? %>
      var build_error = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='build_error'>";
      build_error += "You've got <%= pluralize(@supporter.errors.count, 'error') %>.";
      build_error +=   "<ul id='error_explanation'>";
      <% @supporter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <% if msg === "Ip has already been taken" %>
            <% msg = "You've already posted your support.   Thanks!" %>
        <% end %>
        build_error += "<li><%= j msg %></li>";
      <% end %>
      build_error +=   "</ul>";
      build_error += "</div>";
      $(build_error).insertBefore( "#home_form" );
    <% end %>           
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass a wrong action into the form

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_supporter" id="new_supporter" 
action="/supporters.js" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

Instead of `/supporter.js` should be just `/supporters`

You need to remove `format: :js` from this line:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@supporter, remote: true, format: :js) do |f| %>
```

Comment: hey thanks man.   so now it goes to /supporters, and the text doesn't appear, but it is supposed to just refresh the form on the page, and refresh the supporters/show_supporters in the #home_list.

Comment: Alex figured it out - didn't have teether installed so the bootstrap was failing.